# Uniform convergence of $x^n \sin(\frac{1-x}{x})$ on (0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I'm attempting to determine if the funtion
$$f_n(x) = x^n \sin(\frac{1-x}{x})$$
converges uniformly on (0,1). Obviously, the function converges pointwise to $0$. I've graphed the function and the supremum is strictly less than 1 for n=1 and decreasing for successive n's, leading me to believe that the convergence is indeed uniform. I started typing this out with no idea where to start, but I think I might have an idea now and would like feedback on it. My idea is to show that sequence of functions $f_n(x)$ are equicontinous at $1$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. It can be shown that
$$\lim_{x \to 1} x\sin(\frac{1-x}{x}) = 0$$
so there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $x \in (1-\delta, 1)$ gives
$$\left| x\sin(\frac{1-x}{x}) \right| < \epsilon/2.$$
So, for each $n > 1$
$$\left| x^n \sin(\frac{1-x}{x}) \right| \leq \left|x\sin(\frac{1-x}{x}) \right| < \epsilon$$
for $x \in (1-\delta,1)$.
Now for $x \in (0, 1-\delta]$
$$\left| x^n \sin(\frac{1-x}{x}) \right| \leq \left|x^n \right| \leq \left| 1-\delta \right|^n.$$
Since $(1 - \delta) < 1$, we can find $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N$ gives
$$\left| 1- \delta \right|^n < \epsilon.$$
Thus for $n \geq N$, we have
$$\left|x^n \sin( \frac{1-x}{x} ) \right| < \epsilon$$
for all $x \in (0,1)$, showing that $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $0$.

Comment: Your explanation looks fine to me.